# Appsmith to change the default value of the Input Box

Tags: appsmith

### The Process

I am going to use Appsmith to edit the item price using rest API

### The Item List Table

[image]

### Code

`{{menitems.data.content}}`

### Explanation

From the Image, I have been Displaying my Item with the Edit Button in a table that I got from Rest API
While Clicking I have been showing Item's details and the price to be changed

### While Clicking the Edit Price Button

I have been Passing the Price from **Table** to the javascript object which I have been using **storevalue** to store the price which I will get the price and show in the popup

### Code for Passing Table data to the Javascript Object

`{{priceCalculation.openModal(currentRow.pricetype,currentRow.price)}}`

### Description

I have been passing the price from the table to the popup using the above code

### Javascript Object code Open a Modal and storeValue

`openModal:(price) => {storeValue("price",price);}`

### Description

Then in the Javascript object, I have been using storeValue to save in a local storage

### The Modal Popup

[image]

### Explanation

As you can see I have been getting the price from storeValue and adding in the input box's Default Value

### In the Popup Price Input

`{{appsmith.store.pricebefore}}`

### Description

From the above code I have been adding the price from the store value

### Problem

When I change the text it rolls back the value from the storeValue

### For Example

- price in storeValue = 300
- if I tried to change the price input to = 200
- then the input price rolls back to = 300

### Solution Tried

in the price Input **onTextChanged**
`{{(function({storeValue("pricebefore",price_before_discount.text);priceCalculation.price_before_change(price_before_discount.text);})()}}`

### Description

In the above code I have to change the text in storeValue too but it's way too slow if I edit too fast like double clear and add text way fast then it's taking too much time to reflect by the time it reflects it's rolling back the value in storeValue

### For Example:

- The Text in Input = 12345
- if I press double bacspace then it's too slow it only clears one
- in the price input **onSubmit**
- If I use this it's working fine on Desktop but on mobile I can't
  submit the Input there is no Tick button on keyboard

### Conclusion

I just need an alternative using the process of getting the price from the table and putting in the input and allowing the user to edit that input without interference